# Check username availabilit using AJAX and JSP error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery

I want to check if a username is available or not, I have this jquery call to my jsp which is called on click of a button

```
 function lookup(inputString) 
 {
        $.post("CheckUsername.jsp",{user: ""+inputString+""},function(data){
        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data).show();
        });
 }
```

in my CheckUsername.jsp i have a simple array to which I check the inputString for existing name

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
 {
      if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(names[i])) count++;  
 } 
 if(count==0)
 { 
      out.println("UserName is Available"); 
 }
 else 
 {
      out.println("Username is not available"); 
 }
```

The problem is that once I click the button on the page it does nothing but when  I click it second time it works properly. Why is this happening. Please help

Comment: Can you try inspecting requests from browser, for FF press CTRL +SHIFT +K

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am checking the firebug, on first click it fires Get request and 404.jsp and it goes on, on 2nd click it successfully fires post request and gets the response and shows on the div. Satya: button code is this <input type="button" id="check" value="check" onclick="lookup(userName.value);"/>  userName is a <s:textfield>

Comment: post your button's HTML please

Comment: @JigarJoshi <input type="button" id="check" value="check" onclick="lookup(userName.value);"/>

Comment: I guess, you are saving `userName.value` in a variable at pageload. And when you click it for first time, its sending '' (blank username)

Comment: Can you check what is passed in the first request. And what is the url fired.

Comment: On the first request its firing a GET request nothing is getting passed and on the second one its firing proper post request along with the userName

Comment: I got it working by changing the $post to $get. Now its working fine on first click.

Comment: @SandiipPatil: It is good practice to answer the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I never use jquery post. jQuery.ajax work fine for me:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "<c:url value='CheckUsername.jsp'/>",
   type: "POST",
   data: "yourdata"
   success: function() {
       jQuery('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data).show();
   }
});
```

jQuery.ajax never give me GET when I want POST.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the POST to GET

```
 function lookup(inputString) 
 {
    $.get("CheckUsername.jsp",{user: ""+inputString+""},function(data){
    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data).show();
    });
 }
```

This works for me.